# Unable to fix bread crumb structure in wordpress to display "blog"

Tags: wordpress, breadcrumbs

I can't figure out how to fix the bread crumb menu for my www.example.com/blog/ page and each blog posts respectively using the code below. On the blog page, it displays the title of my first blog post instead of my page title (h1 tag).

Current Result:

Home > 5 Easy Lunch Ideas When You Are On The Go

Expected Result:

Home > Blog

On my blog posts, the bread crumb structure doesn't show the correct hierarchy; it skips over the "blog" menu item

Current Result:

Home >  10 Ways To Increase Productivity In The Morning

Desired Result:

Home > Blog > 10 Ways To Increase Productivity In The Morning

Add below code into your themes functions.php file.

```
function breadcrumbs($id = null){
?>
<div id="breadcrumbs">
    <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">Home</a></span> >
    <?php if(!empty($id)): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $id ); ?>" ><?php echo get_the_title( $id ); ?></a> >
    <?php endif; ?>
    <span class="breadcrumb_last"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
</div>
<?php }
```

Add to header.php

```
<?php breadcrumbs(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the way the breadcrumb code is set up, you will need to run a check to see if you are currently on a blog page, and if you are, add the text in between the last breadcrumb item & the home one.

This can be done by utilising the global wp_query, in combination with the function is_simple(). This has now been tested and seems to work.

```php
function breadcrumbs($id = null) {

    $blogTitle = get_the_title( get_option('page_for_posts', true) );
    global $wp_query; ?>

    <div id="breadcrumbs">

        <span><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">Home</a></span>

        <?php if ( isset( $wp_query ) && (bool) $wp_query->is_posts_page ) { ?>
            > <?php echo $blogTitle; ?></span>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if ( is_single() ) { ?>
            > <span><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ); ?>"><?php echo $blogTitle; ?></a></span> >
            <span><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></span>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if (is_page() ) { ?>
            > <span><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></span>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if (is_search() ) { ?>
            > <span> Search results: <?php echo the_search_query(); ?></span>
        <?php } ?>

    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

Hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168770/discussion-on-answer-by-calico-unable-to-fix-bread-crumb-structure-in-wordpress).